# Internal Server Error in my Code?

Tags: python, html, utf-8, http-status-code-500

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi
import cgitb
import urllib.request
import os
import sys

def enco_print(string="", encoding = "utf8"):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(string.encode(encoding) + b"\n")

cgitb.enable()


form = cgi.FieldStorage(endcoding="utf8")

name_name= form.getvalue("name")
url_name = form.getvalue("url")


response = urllib.request.urlopen(str(url_name)) 
html = response.read().decode("utf8")

if not os.path.exists("gecrwalt"):
    os.mkdir("gecrwalt")      


with open("/gecrwalt/" + str(url_name) + ".html", "w", endcoding="utf8")
as f:
f.write(str(html))
```

When I try to run this script, I get 500 Status Error on my Website. I can´t see what´s wrong with this code.

I´m very thankful for help.

Comment: The very first line should be the path to the Python interpreter.... yours has backticks and enter your code here listed there too... is that what it says in the real file?

Comment: I´m not sure that I got this. Isn´t the first line the path? Because I was told to do this that way.

Comment: A minute ago the path had "insert code here"... seems ok now

Comment: Oh, okay :-) . But you can´t see the mistake? I thought maybe I didn´t wirte the right permissions (755) and that´s why it doesn´t work.

Comment: Sorry, not a Python guy so can't spot what's wrong

Comment: Okay ;-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos where you wrote `endcoding` instead of `encoding`.

The last segment here

```
with open("/gecrwalt/" + str(url_name) + ".html", "w", endcoding="utf8")
as f:
f.write(str(html))
```

has broken indentation, not sure if this was due to a copy-paste error here on Stackoverflow.

Another issue here is that (if I understood your code correlty) `url_name` will contain a complete URL like `http://example.com`, which will result in an error because that filename is invalid. You will have to come up with some schema to safely store these files, urlencode the URL or take a hash of the URL. Your save path also starts with `/`, not sure if intentational, starts at the file system root.

Changing the typo and the last bit has worked for me in a quick test:

```
with open("gecrwalt/something.html", "w", endcoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(str(html))
```

Debugging hint: I started a local Python webserver process with this command ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30516779/1781026))

```
python3 -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi 8000
```

Accessing `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/filename.py` will show you all errors that occur, not sure about the webserver you are currently using (there should be error logs somewhere I guess).

Comment: chrki at first: thank you very much. You helped me a lot and I didn´t see the mistakes. After I changed these typos and mistakes, I get now Status Error 405. Do you know why? :-)

Comment: @user8067545 Are you able to execute the script like this? `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/filename.py?name=test&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com` -- 405 means "Method not allowed", I'm guessing here: if you have a `<form>` somewhere change `method="POST"` to `method="GET"`... might be stuff for a separate question though