# СGI python3 403 error

Tags: python, cgi

I am asking it because I write very simply app but IT DON'T WORK.
I wrote this command in terminal in the `/dir`:

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

My script is in dir/cgi-bin/hp.py and that code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print"Content-type: text/html"
print()
print"<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
```

This I saw in window of browser:

> Error response
>   Error code: 403
>   Message: CGI script is not executable ('/cgi-bin/hp.py').
>   Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN - Request forbidden --
>   authorization will not help."

How can I fix it?

Comment: @bhansa It doesn't fix my error =(

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516414/how-to-run-cgi-hello-world-with-python-http-server

Comment: @bhansa it dosen't helped me. Interesting, that if I am runing Flask server for developers then everything is good. And if I am runing "socets-server", then also everything is good. But CGI -server doesn't work.

Comment: Read about [howto-linux-bsd-listing-permissions-of-file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-bsd-listing-permissions-of-file/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the following steps which I tried to reproduce the problem:

```
# app.py
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

1. Created a file `app.py` in `cgi-bin` directory
2. Used command to run http.server with cgi

   - `python -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi 8000`

I tried accessing the path `"http:localhost/cgi-bin/"` got *Error 403*

Now the **resolving** part, which is opening the link in browser.

I ran the command:

```
python -mwebbrowser http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/app.py
```

After the while it gave me the result, and I was able to access the link for the step 2 also.

I hope that helps you.

Result:

[image: Result screenshot]

Comment: Conflict of user access because app.py was create with limited opportunities (as me =) but run python-server was started as standard-user and not root. I created file as root and started server as root and everything is ok