# how run a python script with a html button?

Tags: python, html, button

i just would like to run a python script by clicking on a html button.
python script is reallly simple. when you run it, it just add a "name" and "age" data in my database.

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('bdaremplir.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

"""cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS latable')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE latable (noms TEXT, age INTEGER)')"""



nom = 'TheName'
age = 100

cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO latable (noms, age) VALUES ( ?, ? )''', (nom, age))
conn.commit()
```

and the basics of html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>visualisateur</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

now from here i don't at all what i can do.
if anyone can help... thank you.

Comment: You'll need to either compile your Python using Emscripten, or use a JavaScript interpreter for python, or send a request to the server and run python server-side. However, keep in mind that since the database exists server-side and not client side, you will *not* be able to run that code client-side.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something about the system (it seems like you just have these two pieces of code), there are several other components you need.  I think starting with a simple web framework like Flask might be the best move.

Comment: To run Python code on the server you’ll need to learn a framework like Django, Flask or Bottle. I have only used Bottle - it’s easy and lightweight and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Web browsers only know how to run JavaScript, not Python, so unless you really want to run Python in the browser<sup>1</sup>, you have to learn about [the client-server architecture of the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction#What_is_server-side_website_programming).

Basically, you have to

1. make your Python program available as a web server, and
2. send a request to that server when your HTML button is clicked.

## Running a web server

There are many ways to implement a web server in Python. When you get to writing a proper application, you'll probably want to use a library like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/), Django, or others. But to get started quickly, you can [use the built-in Python HTTP server with CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516414/how-to-run-cgi-hello-world-with-python-http-server):

1. Create a Python script named `handle_request.py` with the following content:

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    print("Content-Type: text/plain\n")
    print("hello world")
   ```

and put it into the `cgi-bin` directory next to your HTML file and make sure you can run it by typing "handle_request.py" into the console;
2. Run the built-in HTTP server:

```
    python3 -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi 8000
```

3. Open http://localhost:8000 in your browser to access the server.

You should see the listing of the directory, including your HTML file and the `cgi-bin` directory. Clicking the HTML file should display it in the browser (with a URL like http://localhost:8000/test.html), and opening http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/handle_request.py will run the script we've created and display its response as a web page. You can add your code to the script, and it will run whenever the browser accesses its URL.

## Making a request from your web page

Now the question is how to make the browser access the http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/handle_request.py URL when a button on your page is clicked.

To do that you need to invoke the API for making requests from JavaScript. There are different ways to do that (e.g. `XMLHttpRequest` or `jQuery.ajax()`), but a simple way that works in the modern web browsers is `fetch()`:

```
<button id="mybutton"></button>

<script>
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = async function() {
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/handle_request.py");
  let text = await response.text();
  alert(text);
}
</script>
```

Now when you click the button, the browser will make a request to the specified URL (thus running your script), but instead of displaying the results as a web page in a tab, it will be made available to your JavaScript.

## notes

*<sup>1</sup> ...which you probably don't at this point, but if you do, see [the pointers by Michael Bianconi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528526/how-run-a-python-script-with-a-html-button#comment101523128_57528526).*