# How can I link HTML to a python script

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi, openpyxl

I want to link HTML form with an excel document such that the data entered in the form can be directly appended to the excel file. For this I used python modules openpyxl and cgi.

HTML form:

```
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
    <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

python code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import cgi 

 wb = xl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
 ws= wb['Sheet1']

 form = cgi.FieldStorage()
 name= form.getvalue('fname')+' '+form.getvalue('lname')
 age = form.getvalue('age')

 ws.append([name, age])
 wb.save('data.xlsx')
```

But when I run this HTML file on localhost, the python script itself is being displayed and the python program is not executing.

[This is what I am getting when I submit the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uRnK.png)

Update: I enabled cgi in the http request using

```
$ python3 -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi
```

Now I am getting [error 501](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4FOD.png)

Comment: it's not so simple. Look into django or that other one i forget what it's called

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516414/how-to-run-cgi-hello-world-with-python-http-server

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I enabled cgi as suggested but I am still getting an error. I have updated it in the question

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html